# EventBus to notify UI changes

Tags: android, performance, events

In the application which I am developing, I have started to use `EventBus` for notifying that some events inside application occurred. I am wondering if it is good idea to notify other application components (especially `UI` elements) that some `UI` events have appeared.

For example there is a sliding panel and when it is expanded some search field should appear and whenever it is collapsed some other action needs to be done. Is it correct to use `EventBus` here? I am asking this since I have concerns that, if I'm going to use `EventBus` for notifying `UI` events, then some performance issues will appear.

Maybe there is some better way to keep your `UI` elements decoupled and not use EventBus for notifying that some event has appeared?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't really need an event bus for that, you can just register some callbacks or listener and notify the appropriate views that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that inside application there are many different `UI` elements wrapped by different controllers and I would not want to keep them close coupled. I really like the idea that one controller is sending event and another one is responding to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about the GreenRobot Eventbus in this answer.

In that case I do not believe the overhead is a big deal, it scales pretty well in my experience, version 3.0 with annotations is highly optimized it seems.

But the best way is to try out and if you are worried about performance then check that along the way, but it sounds like you would not have problem.
The nice thing with EventBus is also the decoupling as well.